# one column value reference from two tables is it support SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

one column value reference from  two tables is it support SQLITE

see the below table structure

account_id reference from two tables

```
FOREIGN KEY(account_id) REFERENCES account(id),
FOREIGN KEY(account_id) REFERENCES category(id)

CREATE TABLE transaction (
id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY,
user_id NUMERIC NOT NULL,
account_id NUMERIC NOT NULL,
category_id NUMERIC NOT NULL,
amount DOUBLE NOT NULL, date VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(25),
FOREIGN KEY(account_id) REFERENCES account(id),
FOREIGN KEY(account_id) REFERENCES category(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible.

All constraints must be met, i.e., each `account_id` value must appear in *both* parent tables.

Comment: is it mandatory to give id is primary key in account table and category table

Comment: The parent key must have a unique index; primary key is just fine.